# Can't Compile C# Project Template With AppSettings.cs

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2017, appsettings

I have a C# Project Template and I want to add a AppSettings.cs file to be copied over to my newly deployed project that is based off of my template.  However, when I try to build my template project, I get build errors complaining about AppSettings.cs

IMPORTANT: note that this is a C# Project Template which uses variables surrounded by $$, e.g. $safeprojectname$, so removing those $s isn't an option. $safeprojectname$ works in other files, but just not AppSettings.cs.

Here is an example of my AppSettings.cs:

```c#
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace $safeprojectname$
{
    public class AppSettings
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public AppSettings() { }
    }
}
```

The compiler is complaining about my $safeprojectname$ variable saying "{ expected" yet I have the same namespace line used in my Program.cs, Startup.cs, and a few other spots with no issue.

I thought I might have to add the AppSettings.cs file to my Project.vstemplate and ProjectTemplate.csproj files like I did for the other files mentioned above but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

Any suggestions?  Is there some other way of bundling/hiding the AppSettings.cs file from the VS compiler so it stops treating my AppSettings.cs like it is meant for the Project Template Project opposed to my newly deployed template project?

Comment: So I'm pretty certain this has to do with Project Templates specifically.  I'm using "namespace $safeprojectname$" in several files without issue.

Comment: JBC, if I do that, then the Template Variable "safeprojectname" won't be injected on deployment of the template project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
I had to change the Build Action of my AppSettings.cs from Compile to None, which is done via the Properties window or by changing your CSPROJ code shown here:

```c#
<Compile Include="AppSettings.cs" />
```

to

```c#
<None Include="AppSettings.cs" />
```

Thank you to all who viewed and/or commented.